# Trouble changing attribute with shorthand if

Tags: jquery, shorthand-if

I was just wondering if I could get some pointers please.

I am using a shorthand if to change text based on whether a div is toggled.

This is what I have for the text changer:

```
$(this).text($(this).text() == 'Email Me' ? 'Close Form' : 'Email Me');
```

I am wanting to follow along these lines to change the title attribute of an anchor. I have tried it using the following:

```
$(this).text($(this).attr('title', == 'Email Me' ? 'Close Form' : 'Email Me')); //This throws up syntax errors in firebug because of where the == is placed
```

I have also tried it as follows:

```
$(this).text($(this).attr('title') == 'Email Me' ? 'Close Form' : 'Email Me'); //This doesn't change the attribute at all.
```

I think I may just be being really dumb but I can't figure this one out. I have googled it and I can't seem to find a definitive answer on it.

Just wondering if you had any suggestions as to where I may be going wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just wondering if anyone else has been able to check this out and have found a solution.

The issue (from the conversations below) is that the ternary operator is defaulting to false - even though it works just fine in a js fiddle.

I have tried it with a long handed if else statement and it is still defaulting to false. I have tried putting just 123 in both the attribute of the a and also as the comparison with no luck whatsoever

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't you be using `attr` instead?

```
$(this).attr("title", $(this).attr('title') == 'Email Me' ? 'Close Form' : 'Email Me');
```

instead of:

```
$(this).text($(this).attr('title') == 'Email Me' ? 'Close Form' : 'Email Me'); //This doesn't change the attribute at all.
```

Comment: I have tried it with attr and it doesn't seem to want to work. When I first tried it, I thought it would be a case of just changing the text to attr but it doesn't want to play ball. I am not getting any errors in firebug either

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the attribute, change the *attribute*, not the text:

```
$(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('title') == 'Email Me' ? 'Close Form' : 'Email Me');
```

Note that `title` is a reflected property, so you can do this rather more efficiently without jQuery:

```
this.title = this.title == 'Email Me' ? 'Close Form' : 'Email Me';
```

But you'd have to be doing it thousands and thousands of times for the efficiency to matter.

---

The `condition ? value : otherValue` thing is called a "ternary" operator. It's frequently called "the" ternary operator, but "ternary" just means it has three operands (a "binary" operator [like the `+` in `1 + 1`] has two, a "unary" operator [like the `-` in `-n`] has just one), so technically it's "a" ternary operator. I'ts just the only one that most C-like languages have...

Comment: I have tried both methods and neither seem to be working. The latter one of this.title seems to break the jquery and the rest of the function doesn't run. I have tried the former but it doesn't change it and using firebug doesn't show any change either. I must be missing something so silly

Comment: @Chris: Odd. Works for me: http://jsbin.com/ocevoj/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/ocevoj/1/edit) and http://jsbin.com/ocevoj/2 (source: http://jsbin.com/ocevoj/2/edit). Of course, you have to make sure `this` is referring to the `div` you want to change (as it will in a jQuery event handler, for instance).

Comment: @Chris, post your entire code, or create a fiddle, it will be easier to help you since this solution is supposed to work.

Comment: Hi, here is the fiddle [link]http://jsfiddle.net/wilcochris/nDMf8/[/link]

It is working just fine in the fiddle. I try to use it on my page and it doesn't work. It will only work if I have one word in the title attr. I can't fathom it

Comment: @Chris: All due respect, there's not much point in a *working* fiddle. :-) The only thing that comes to mind is the idea that the text in the title you're comparing with is *not* exactly the same as what you're comparing it to. (For instance, do you have a tab character instead of a space?)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I understand that there is no point in a working one. I'm just baffled as to why it doesn't work. I have copied the text from the title and it still won't work.

Looking at it, it is only changing the text to be what is after : It seems to be ignoring == '...' ? '...' : '...' <- this last bit is all it changes it to. Not sure if i'm explaining myself properly

Comment: @Chris: It depends which way you've copied it. I would manually delete everything you think is a space in the HTML and then press the space bar (and again in the JavaScript).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am debugging with firebug and all it seems to be doing is changing the title to whatever is after the : in the operator. I have made sure the title text in the a and the comparison in the operator are the same. It just seems to skip the if operand and go straight to the else operand

Comment: @Chris: Then they're not the same; the `condition` is not true. That is the only explanation.

Comment: I get what you mean, I just don't know how they can be different when I have copied and pasted the title attribute to the condition. I also don't get why the same code works in a fiddle but not on my page. I have tried in a couple of different browsers with the same result. I am stumped

Comment: @Chris: As am I. It's *got* to be some weird whitespace thing, since HTML normalizes whitespace to a single space but JavaScript (of course) doesn't. (Hey, is that it? Does one of your strings have multiple spaces in a row?) In any case, good luck with it!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your input. I'll guess i'll just leave it. All I do know, is that it is skipping the if and going straight to the else. Oh well, will be fun to try and find out why I guess. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this was an issue with a plugin that I have running. I have the tipsy plugin to provide fancy tool tips.

Once I stopped using this for the title attribute on the a tag, the toggle worked perfectly. I just now have to figure out why it is doing this.

Thanks for all your help